# How to save figure with adjusted size?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

So I have a matplotlib figure. Which is generated by this code

```
matplotlib.pyplot.subplots_adjust(left=0.05, bottom=0.1, right=0.95, top=0.94, wspace=0.2, hspace=0.2)
f.autofmt_xdate()
f.savefig('demo.png')
```

it looks like this:
[picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kY7vy.png)

When I use

```
plt.show()
```

and maximize the figure frame and then save it manually, it looks like this:
[picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PXTsI.png)

Now how do I save it like this with the code?

Comment: I have already checked that question, the answers only show how to maximize frame , not to save it like that

Comment: If you `savefig()`after maximising, do you not get the desired result?

Comment: it saves as previously (as in picture 1)

Comment: I added this `figure = plt.gcf()
figure.set_size_inches(13.66, 7.68)` now I does what I wanted